# Python function stop working after some iterations

Tags: python, pandas, loops, finance, quantitative-finance

```
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import *
n=0
Ptf_opp_2=[]
lenght_2=len(Ptf_opp)

def step2():
    for n in range(0,lenght_2):
        Bs=get_balance_sheet(Ptf_opp[n])
        tca=Bs.loc[Bs.get('Breakdown').str.match('Total Current Assets')]
        tl=Bs.loc[Bs.get('Breakdown').str.match('Total Liabilities')]
        tcl=Bs.loc[Bs.get('Breakdown').str.match('Total Current Liabilities')]
        if (tca.iloc[0,1] != None and \
            tca.iloc[0,1] != '-' and \
            tl.iloc[0,1] != None and \
            tl.iloc[0,1] != '-' and \
            tcl.iloc[0,1] != None and \
            tcl.iloc[0,1] != '-' and \
            (float(tcl.iloc[0,1]) / float(tca.iloc[0,1])) < 1.1 and\
            (float(tca.iloc[0,1]) / float(tl.iloc[0,1])) > 1.5):
            Ptf_opp_2.append(Ptf_opp[n]) 
step2()
```

Hello everyone, i'm new with python, i'm trying to make a code for university exam, this is a part of my project, it runs, but after some iterations, the `Bs=get_balance_sheet(Ptf_opp[n])` stops working (really it work but just creates a dataframe `[0,0]` that is useless and isn't correct).

The aim of the code is to create a new dataframe after checking that the ticker contained in `Ptf_opp[n]` satisfies boundary condition below.

Furthermore if someone has any tips to improve my code  I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What is `Ptf_opp`? As a guess, you may be throttled by Yahoo for making to many requests too fast.

Comment: The problem is most likely that either `Ptf_opp[n]` doesn't contain what you expect, or there's a bug in `get_balance_sheet()`. This loop is not the problem.

Comment: @DYZ  _Ptf_opp_ is just a series that contains all ticker i want to test, honestly i thought that it could be a yahoo problem (the problem normally appears after more or less 250 iteration). Have you any kind of suggest to solve it? ex. another way to get financial statement or other things

Comment: @barmar, no "Ptf_opp[n]" is correct, I check it before with other function, also the function works but after 200 iterations this function stops working.

Comment: Add debugging code to `get_balance_sheet()` to see why it's returning `[0, 0]`

Comment: @Barmar `get_balance_sheet` is a function from module `yahoo_fin`, I do not think it can be debugged.

Comment: Consider adding `time.sleep(delay)` to the end of each iteration, where `delay` is time in seconds. A one-second delay often helps. If it does not, try a longer delay.

Comment: @DYZ with a time delay  it works but now i see a strange problem, with my wi-fi (more or less 100 mb/s) connection, also with delay function, it don't work (each time after a different number of iteration), but if i use a phone hotspot in a place with a medium level of connection, the code run without problem. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do: `from yahoo_fin.stock_info import *`

Do: `from yahoo_fin import stock_info`

`stock_info.get_balance_sheet` then identifies where the function it is coming from

I'm going to guess you are hitting a rate limit on the use of the API, provided that function is actually contacting yahoo